# Creating new Virtual Machine in Microsoft Hyper-V server 2012 r2

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am new to Windows Hyper-V server 2012 r2, trying to create new virtual machine in ther Hyper-V server.

Try to follow http://www.danielclasson.com/guide-how-to-create-and-configure-virtual-machines-in-hyper-v-server-2012-using-powershell/

But got stuck in *.iso file for the Windows installation:
Not able to copy iso file within the hyper-v server.

Any proper step should i follow, suggestions, help.......

thanks in advance

Comment: What command are you executing? What is the error message you see?

Comment: I am not able to locate the iso file, meant i was not able to bring it to the hyper-v server itself.

Comment: The iso needs to be on a disk that the host can access.

Comment: meant i should use a bootable disk to start the VM? ok thanks

Comment: Now things all went fine, but when i start the VM " 
Start-VM –Name DC" getting error " The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine, because one of the Hyper-V components is not running

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that Intel VT and all virtualisation capabilities like VT / V and Trusted Execution Prevention / Data Execution Prevention are enabled in BIOS (it may have other names in your BIOS).

2) Make sure your BIOS is up to date

3) Please refer following URL for Wordkaround suggested at MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545448(v=vs.85).aspx#when_to_use_dv

This workaround suggests that disabling the I/O verification option in Driver Verifier for all drivers on the hostcomputer resolves this issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2761004

Answer (score -1):

Above information is useful but I also find the step by step way to install windows os in hyper v manager in windows server 2012 at following links

http://www.ittechpoint.com/2016/04/how-to-install-windows-os-in-hyper-v-manager-in-windows-server-2012-R2.html

Comment: This looks like a link only answer ...